# Implementing flutter ui

Tags: flutter, gridview

[image]

I have been trying to recreate this ui where the gridview

This is what I have tried so far

```
 GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                primary: true,
                gridDelegate:
                    const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisExtent: 300,
                ),
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final model = result[index];
                  return MyContainer(
                    loanProductModel: model,
                  );
                },
              )
```

[image: Grid view]

This is the screenshot of what I have tried.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I just want help on how to implement this kind of Ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `flutter_staggered_grid_view` package and the below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            sliver: SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 9.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 9.0,
                staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                    StaggeredTile.count(1, index % 5 == 0 ? 1.5 : 1.2),
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                  final model = result[index];
                  return MyContainer(
                    loanProductModel: model,
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```